# Retrieve background location using WorkManager always return same lastknown location

Tags: android, background, location, android-workmanager

My app works fine if using foreground service to get user location, however in background I just need location for each 15 minutes, also `Google` requires new [Policy for getting background location](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9799150?hl=en&ref_topic=2364761) so, foreground service is over my expectation.

I am trying to get location from background using `WorkManager`, it can run normally every (around) 15 minutes. My location is requested, however it always returns the previous address, even 1, 2... hours are passed.

Here is my code:

```kotlin
class LocationWorker(private val context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :
        CoroutineWorker(context, params) {
    
   private var fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
  
   override suspend fun doWork() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      val location = getLocation()
      if (location == null) {
         if (runAttemptCount < MAX_ATTEMPT) { // max_attempt = 3
            Result.retry()
         } else {
            Result.failure()
         }
      } else {
         Log.d(TAG, "doWork success $location")
         Result.success()
      }
    }
    
    private suspend fun getLocation(): Location? = withTimeoutOrNull(TIMEOUT) {
       suspendCancellableCoroutine<Location?> { continuation ->
          val intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, Intent(ACTION), 0)
          val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
              override fun onReceive(context: Context?, data: Intent?) {
                  if (data?.action != ACTION) return
                  val lastLocation = LocationResult.extractResult(data)?.lastLocation
                  Log.e(TAG, "Get lastLocation success $lastLocation")
                  fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(intent)
                  context?.unregisterReceiver(this)
                  continuation.resume(lastLocation)
              }
        }
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(ACTION))
        val request = LocationRequest().apply { priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY }
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, intent)
        continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
            fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(intent)
            context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
        }
    }
    
    companion object {
            val TAG = LocationWorker::class.java.simpleName
            const val LOCATION_WORKER_TAG = "LOCATION_WORKER_TAG"
            const val MAX_ATTEMPT = 3
            private const val ACTION = "my.background.location"
            private const val TIMEOUT = 60_000L
            private const val REQUEST_CODE = 888
        }
    }
```

Pre-condition:

- Tested device: emulator android 27 (O_MR1)
- Route Play normally
- GPS is enabled
- Allow location permission (allow all time)

Why the `lastknown location` not updated ?

I also tried this demo https://github.com/pratikbutani/LocationTracker-WorkManager/ . However, the problem is same, `lastknown location` is not updated.

Comment: Hi! Have you figured it out?

Comment: @nutella_eater I didn't remember the result, we changed the requirement cause user will never uses "allows all time", you may try the code in real device (try to make timer lower).

Answer (score 0):

The previous location gets cached.
Clear the cache before you store the new location in `lastknown location`

Comment: Yeah, in the question, it said the location did not update, that means previous location gets cached. So, why ? and how do you clear the cache ?

Comment: the location get cached because of some internal android studio bug, even i have no idea why it happens, you could clear the cache by calling `cache.clear()` or some similar function before storing the new value

Comment: I don't think it relates to AS because Emulator can simulate the route. When simulating, the location is emitted every second, they are caught normally in foreground case. This issue only happens when I get location in background.